# Grails 5 app is constantly redeploying during development

Tags: grails

I had been using Grails 3.3.2 for about 3-4 years now and never had this issue.  I just recently started migrating our apps to Grails 5 and now this started happening.  Everytime I save a change to a file (gson, groovy, etc) the app redeploys and I have to wait a good 5-6 seconds before I can test it (url becomes available).

In Grails 5 my console looks like this when I make changes:

```
Grails application running at http://localhost:8081 in environment: development
File C:\Workspaces\Intellij\ecpp\grails-app\controllers\ecpp\service\LookupSvcController.groovy changed, recompiling...
Grails application running at http://localhost:8081 in environment: development
File C:\Workspaces\Intellij\ecpp\grails-app\controllers\ecpp\service\LookupSvcController.groovy changed, recompiling...
Grails application running at http://localhost:8081 in environment: development
File C:\Workspaces\Intellij\ecpp\grails-app\controllers\ecpp\service\LookupSvcController.groovy changed, recompiling...
Grails application running at http://localhost:8081 in environment: development
```

Each one of those `Grails application running [...]` lines is a 5+ second delay I have to wait through before the app comes back up

When I would work on my 3.3.2 projects my console would look like this during changes

```
Grails application running at http://localhost:8081 in environment: development
File C:\Workspaces\Intellij\ecpp\grails-app\controllers\ecpp\service\LookupSvcController.groovy changed, recompiling...
File C:\Workspaces\Intellij\ecpp\grails-app\controllers\ecpp\service\LookupSvcController.groovy changed, recompiling...
File C:\Workspaces\Intellij\ecpp\grails-app\controllers\ecpp\service\LookupSvcController.groovy changed, recompiling...
```

I never had to wait, I could immediately refresh the page and see the changes.  Needless to say, my DEV time has taken a hit having to stop and wait for a redeploy.  Is there some configuration I missed while upgrading that I can set to resolve this?

This happens while running the app with `gradlew bootRun` as well as `grailsw run-app`

Grails 5.1.7

JDK: 11.0.13

Comment: mine does that too for grails 5.1 ;  now development became really difficult. Every change in controllers, or services will require a restart of application which takes a few minutes :(  Any clue why is that or is there a way around that?? we want fast reload as before which used to take a few seconds only

Answer (score 1):

> I just recently started migrating our apps to Grails 5 and now this
> started happening. Everytime I save a change to a file (gson, groovy,
> etc) the app redeploys and I have to wait a good 5-6 seconds before I
> can test it (url becomes available).

The behavior you described is expected and by design.

Older versions of Grails were configured by default with a reloading agent.  Grails 5 is not.  The default behavior you will get with Grails 5 is a recompile and restart.  If you don't want that behavior you can remove the devtools from your build.

You didn't ask about configuring a reloading agent but if you are interested, see the **Spring Boot Developer Tools and Spring Loaded** section at https://docs.grails.org/5.1.7/guide/single.html#upgrading33x.

Comment: What should be done to "remove devtools from build"? thanks.

Comment: Also in the docs it seems there is no way of going back to the previous behavior of reloading the modified resource only instead of restarting the whole application. IMO is a pain for each small change to reload the whole app and wait for the bootstrap to finish, basically a restart time to 4 minutes with 20 changes requires 1 hour 20 minutes, before that was a couple of seconds. Quite a drawback for Grails devs.

Comment: "What should be done to "remove devtools from build"? thanks." - You could remove the depenency on `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools` from your `build.gradle` file.